# Using Mathf.Clamp in unity for boundries

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boundary

I am making a 2D space shooter mobile game. I am trying to set a boundary so the ship does not go out of the screen. You can move the ship by tilting your phone. I have a shipController.cs attached to my ship object. And this is my FixedUpdate function:

```
public float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //tilt to move ship
    transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x * speed, Input.acceleration.y * speed, 0);

    //create boundries
    rigidbody2D.position = new Vector2(
        Mathf.Clamp(rigidbody2D.position.x, xMin, xMax), 
        Mathf.Clamp(rigidbody2D.position.y, yMin, yMax)
    );
}
```

The min and max values are defined in unity inspector.
This code works great if you are testing on pc. But when exporting to the phone, the movement is very jittery and glitches. The ship will get to the boundary and kind of start jumping. The movement when tilting is also not very smooth. Is there any other way to make this smoother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code into `Update` instead of `FixedUpdate`. I'm guessing that there are multiple updates called between fixed updates. For that reason the ship is getting first over the boarder at multiple frames and then returned at the next fixed update.

When using `Update`, you need to handle delta time yourself. Otherwise the speed would be different in different fps. This can be done by simply multiplying the speed with `DeltaTime`:

```
public float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
void Update()
{
    //tilt to move ship
    transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x * speed * Time.DeltaTime, Input.acceleration.y * speed * Time.DeltaTime, 0);

    //create boundries
    transform.position = new Vector2(
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, xMin, xMax), 
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, yMin, yMax)
    );
}
```

After multiplying with `DeltaTime` the value of `speed` is probably way too small. So you need to use some time to find proper value for it again.

Comment: This fixed the smooth issue when the ship is moving, but as soon as it hits the border, it still kind of jumps. And i did change it to update.

Comment: Without seeing jumping, my next guess is that `transform.Translate` is affecting the position straight away, but `rigidbody2D.position` is sent to physics engine but updated result is seen in the next frame. Try changing `rigidbody2D.position` to `transform.position`. I edited the code in my original answer to correspond this.

Comment: That is totally amazing. that worked perfect. I cant believe i didn't try that. I guess that's what you get when you stare at code for so long. thank you.